# Standard (or free) POSIX path manipulation C library

Tags: c, path-manipulation

Is there any standard (or widely used) simple POSIX path manipulation library for C (path join, filename stripping, etc.) ?

Actually, because I'm mostly working under Windows, I currently use ['shlwapi'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) path functions.

Is there any equivalent set of functions available for POSIX paths?

Comment: Offhand: Since multiple `/` don't hurt anything, and there is no such thing as an “extension” in POSIX systems, a lot of those methods aren't significant… you can usually get by with string manipulation, and `realpath` or `glob`. Not technically an answer to what you were asking, though… :-)

Comment: @BRPocock: Multiple `/`es aren't always safe - eg in [kpathsea](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html), `/foo//` expands to all subdirectories under `/foo` (which can be extremely difficult to track down, if you're passing a path to something that uses kpathsea internally - such as latex).

Comment: @timothy Jones ... true, although in my world relatively rare ... but realpath does correct that, as well as symlinks... as does, in its way, glob.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- path join - snprintf()
- filename stripping - dirname()
- etc. - basename(), realpath(), readlink(), glob(), fnmatch()...

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of functions I had in mind. Do you happen to know an online list of those, like an equivalent of the msdn page I linked ?

Comment: Just asking, I already tried to google this, but failed to find any synthetic information ; the noise/signal ratio is quite high as these function also exist in PHP, Ruby, etc. Anyways...

Comment: Thanks for the link, it seems that some functions such as 'basename()' are in this manual in the section 'Finding Tokens in a String'...

Comment: @rotoglup "man snprintf" should have all the information you need. :)